# How to translate a pandas column

Tags: python, json, pandas, sentiment-analysis, translate

I'm working on arabic sentiment analysis project. In my unsupervised learning approach I'm trying to translate the lexicon to arabic using googletrans library.
the lexicon['word'] column contains all the English words.
I tried the following methods:

```
-lexicon['ngram'] = lexicon['word'].apply(translator.translate, src='en', dest='ar')
-lexicon["ngram"] = lexicon["word"].map(lambda x: translator.translate(x, src="en", dest="ar").text)
-lexicon["ngram"] = translator.translate(lexicon["word"], src="en", dest="ar").text
```

they all keep giving me the same error:

`**JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**`

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, although I copied it exactly as I found it on stackoverflow.
My lexicon contains almost 7000 words, and I read that it can take up to 15k words at the same time to translate. can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe, try to convert `lexicon['word']` to string first then use apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the below line

```
lexicon['ngram'] = lexicon['word'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='ar').text)
```

I simulated the below code and it's translating the words

```
import pandas as pd
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator(service_urls=[
      'translate.google.com',
      'translate.google.co.kr',
    ])
words = ['quick', 'brown', 'fox']
lexicon = pd.DataFrame(words, columns=['word'])
lexicon['ngram'] = lexicon['word'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='ar').text)
lexicon
```

Output -

```
  word  ngram
0  quick  بسرعة
1  brown    بنى
2    fox   ثعلب
```